# Is there a way to strip all the electrons from single atom with atomic number greater than 2

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

1. Please explain by what means electrons extraction can be done.
2. How person can focus activity on single atom (from precision point of view) to do so?
3. How at each step person can know how much electrons have been removed till now?

Comment: There are experiments that strip all electrons from e.g. lead and gold atoms. RHIC is an accelerator facility that does that and so is LHC. Here is a description of how it's done: http://alicematters.web.cern.ch/?q=makinglead. The stripping is a multi-step process If you want to be more technical, search for "heavy ion foil stripping": https://www.google.com/search?q=heavy+ion+stripping+foil&oq=heavy+ion+stripping+foil&aqs=chrome..69i57.4374j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

> Please explain by what means electrons extraction can be done.

Hot enough [plasmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) have all the electrons in the plasma leaving the nuclei positive.

> How person can focus activity on single atom (from precision point of view) to do so?

One cannot deal with individual atoms. It is a statistical phenomenon and one can get a beam of ions without any electrons from a plasma, as is done in the [link](http://alicematters.web.cern.ch/?q=makinglead) provided by CuriousOne.

> How at each step person can know how much electrons have been removed till now

See above. Plasma is a phase and is a thermodynamic state.

> A plasma can be created by heating a gas or subjecting it to a strong electromagnetic field, applied with a laser or microwave generator. This decreases or increases the number of electrons, creating positive or negative charged particles called ions, and is accompanied by the dissociation of molecular bonds, if present.

If one wants completely stripped nuclei from electrons, a [fully ionized plasma,](https://www.plasma-universe.com/Plasma_classification_(types_of_plasma)#Fully_ionized_plasma) one has to have a high enough temperature .